# EditText in ListView changes or duplicates content while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, textwatcher

I have two EditTexts in my ListView. All I want is adding a TextWatcher to both the EditTexts , so I can avoid duplicating and changing values in it while scrolling. I can successfully add the TextWatcher to one of the EditTexts, but could not implement for two EditTexts. I tried other answers from stackoverflow. But I didn't get desired output.
This is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.orders);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
     this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
       SelectItems();
    ViewItems();
    }
public List<Map<String, String>> SelectItems() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
try {

       datas = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
    newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("select distinct im_code ,im_desc ,im_srp"
            + " from itemmaster", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
        while (c.moveToNext()){
    datanums.put("name",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_desc"))); 
          datanums.put("code", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_code")));
          datanums.put("imsrp",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_srp"))); 
       datas.add(datanums);
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
       }
return datas; 
}
public void ViewItems() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    arrTemp = new String[datas.size()];
     MyListAdapter myListAdapter = new MyListAdapter();
        list.setAdapter(myListAdapter);
     }
 public  class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
     @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(datas != null && datas.size() != 0){
                return datas.size();    
            }
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return datas.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            //ViewHolder holder = null;
            final  ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                LayoutInflater inflater = Orders.this.getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_simple_row, null);
                holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.srp);
                holder.textview3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);

                holder.editText1 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cases);    
                holder.editText2 = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pcs); 

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
          holder.ref = position;
            String [] names = new String[550];
            String [] codes = new String[550];
            String [] prize = new String[550];

                DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(Orders.this.getApplicationContext());
            newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("select distinct im_code ,im_desc ,im_srp "
                    + " from itemmaster", null);
            Log.v("item detailss", c.toString());   
                c.moveToFirst();

                while (c.moveToNext()){


               String cod = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_code"));
             codes[c.getPosition()] =cod;
                String desc1  = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_desc"));
                names[c.getPosition()] = desc1;

                 String price = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("im_srp"));
                prize[c.getPosition()] = price;

                }
            newDB.close();
                 holder.textView1.setText(names[position+1]);
                holder.textview3.setText(codes[position+1]);
                     holder.textView2.setText(prize[position+1]);

            holder.editText1.setText(arrTemp[holder.ref]);

            holder.editText2.setText(arrTemp[holder.ref]);
           holder.editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                      }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    arrTemp[holder.ref] = arg0.toString();
             datas.get(position).put("pref", holder.editText1.toString().trim());
                }
            });
 return convertView;
    }
        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView1,textView2,textview3;
         EditText editText1,editText2;
           public  int ref;
            }
    }
```

please help me to do this in right way.

Comment: i mean you did't add this `holder.editText2.` ??

Comment: when i am adding that like in my code, it changes value while scrolling

Comment: add `convertView=null; if (convertView == null) {`

Comment: let me inform it works or not

Comment: its not working. when i am adding text watcher to both of the edit texts , in after text I put the same piece of code , by just changing the edit text id. i think that's why its not working correctly. using both the text watcher causes to change the value in both the edit text as same value. I don't know what exactly I will write inside the text watcher to avoid this.

Comment: Both edit text are accessing and setting `arrTemp[holder.ref]` so they will have the same value after scrolling, not at that instant though.

Comment: to add textwatchers to edit text which is inside the listview. do it inside the adapter getitem() .

Comment: Listview with two edittexts, Then TextWatcher is not a good idea. You will face same problem as `CheckBox` in listview. You better use `setOnEditorActionListener` or `onTouchListner`

Comment: @shadow what else I can use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I had a similar problem, here is how I solved it using HashMap:

In the adapter constructor, initialize HashMap and make sure to clear it:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] texts){
    this.context = context;
    this.texts = texts;

    hashMapTexts = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(String text: texts){
        hashMapTexts.put(text, "");
}
```

Then, correct your private class ViewHolder inside the adapter like that:

```
private class ViewHolder {

    private TextView listItemTextView;
    private EditText listItemEditText;
    private int position;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        listItemTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);
        listItemEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_edit_text);
    }
}
```

Then, initialize the ViewHolder in the overriden getView() method:

```
if(convertView == null){
        convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.list_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}
```

Get the position of the ViewHolder in the same method:

```
viewHolder.position = position;
```

Set the texts for your views:

```
    viewHolder.listItemTextView.setText(texts[position]);
    viewHolder.listItemEditText.setText(hashMapTexts.get(texts[position]));
```

and now use the TextWatcher:

```
viewHolder.listItemFormEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            hashMapTexts.put(texts[viewHolder.position], s.toString());
    }
});

return convertView;
```

I suggest you to start with easier case, like mine, then apply it to your specific scenario.

Comment: Thank you...at last it get sorted out..thanks for the detailed description.

Answer (score 0):

> Use different textwatchers for each edit text if you want to perform
>   different operations on each edit text

```
EditText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

> Apply same for other EditText too

Comment: I know this method. But my exact problem is I don't have an idea about what to write inside it , to avoid duplicating and changing values while scrolling

Answer (score -1):

```
et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```